# "Too many open files" Error using boost::filesystem to obtain directory contents

Tags: c++, boost

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [General strategies for memory/speed problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860603/general-strategies-for-memory-speed-problems)

I have a code previously mentioned in [General strategies for memory/speed problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860603/general-strategies-for-memory-speed-problems), which is throwing this error:

```
boost::filesystem::directory_iterator::construct: Too many open files
```

in addition to (seemingly) hogging all of my system resources and slowing down my program.

I'm processing hundreds to thousands of files, and frequently making calls to get the contents of directories using the code included below.  Each file is basically identical, and very little memory should be growing throughout the program---but, the program's speed rapidly slows to a snail's pace, and later crashes with the above error.

I'm guessing that boost is leaving essentially all of the directories open in memory somewhere.... but I'm not sure where/how etc.  Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

```
static bool FileOps::getDirectoryContents(const string dirName, vector<string> *conts);

bool getDirectoryContents(const string dirName, vector<string> *conts) {
    path p(dirName);
    try {
        // Confirm Exists
        if(!exists(p)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: '%s' does not exist!\n", dirName.c_str());
            return false;
        }

        // Confirm Directory
        if(!is_directory(p)) {
            return false;
        }

        conts->clear();

        // Store paths to sort later
        typedef vector<path> vec;
        vec v;

        copy(directory_iterator(p), directory_iterator(), back_inserter(v));

        sort(v.begin(), v.end()); 

        for(vec::const_iterator it(v.begin()), it_end(v.end()); it != it_end; ++it) {
            conts->push_back(it->string());
        }


    } catch(const filesystem_error& ex) {
        // THROWS ERROR: "boost::filesystem::directory_iterator::construct: Too many open files"
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: '%s'!\n", ex.what());
        return false;
    }   

    return true;
}
```

Comment: @broknekk: 1.48.0_3 installed via macports

Comment: did you solve this issue I have the same error?